# Java is not running inside eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have downloaded the `ADT bundle` via this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. The problem is that when I open a project in Eclipse, I am told that `import java.util.List;` can't be resolved. In fact `java` seems not to be recognized although I see that my `JRE` is set correctly . How can I solve that ?

Comment: @Keyser should I uninstall JRE. Btw, where can I find `JDK` ? I thought it was packaged in the `ADT bundle`

Comment: @Keyser sorry but I am using a mac, so I thought it was built-in. Btw, I have `intelliJ idea` and `java` runs fine

Comment: @Keyser yes `javac -version` outputs `javac 1.6.0_51`

Comment: @Keyser btw, sorry I am a newbie to `java`, to install `JDK` should I store it in some specific folder ? Btw, is it safe to install again `JDK` since `java` runs fine in my other ice `intelliJ idea` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35390/discussion-between-user1611830-and-keyser)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. Open a terminal and type javac -version, the output should be something like "javac 1.7.0_25", if not then it is probably not setup
2. In eclipse Project -> clean... and clean all projects
3. Close all open projects and then open them again (Right click on project => "Close Project")

If note of the above work, you should uninstall-download-reinstall the ADT Bundle again

Comment: I installed the latest JDK and set it as my JRE with the right path, but I still get the same problem. Then I downloaded and installed a fresh `eclipse ` and then the `android SDK`, but I still get the same error. Have you an idea ?